# ImportError: cannot import name 'IPV6_ADDRZ_RE' from 'urllib3.util.url'

Tags: python, importerror, urllib3

I am trying to run a .ipynb file using jupyter notebook but I'm getting this error.

I've been scouring the internet for days but nothing seems to work. What I've tried:

- install the 'urlib3.util.url 'packages
- pip install -Iv botocore==1.17
- uninstall then reinstall urllib3
- upgrade urllib3

[here's a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foCAd.png)

Comment: What version of `urllib3` is installed? You need at least `1.25.4`.

Comment: @RandomDavis I installed 1.25.11

Comment: And you're sure that's the version that's actually being run on the notebook? Like, you've verified you're installing it to the correct environment and all that?

Comment: @RandomDavis I just checked on the environments tab and the urllib installed is 1.24 so that might be it. I'm waiting for it to update to the right version and hopefully it works. Thanks so much!